# How can I join multiple SQL tables using the IDs?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 4 different tables that I want to join. The tables are structured with columns as follows:

```
TableA - aID | nameA | dID

TableB - bID | nameB | cID | aID

TableC - cID | nameC | date

TableD - dID | nameD
```

Starting with Table A, I understand how to JOIN tables a and c using b, since b has the Primary Keys for those tables. I want to be able to join table TableD on TableA as well. Below is my SQL statement that first joins tables A and B, then joins that to C:

```
SELECT TableA.*, TableB.*, TableC.* FROM (TableB INNER JOIN TableA
ON TableB.aID= TableA.aID)
INNER JOIN TableC ON(TableB.cID= Tablec.cID)
WHERE (DATE(TableC.date)=date(now()))
```

When I attempt to add another join, to include D, I get an error that 'TableD' is unknown:

```
 SELECT TableA.*, TableB.*, TableC.*, TableD.* FROM (TableB INNER JOIN TableA
    ON TableB.aID= TableA.aID)
    INNER JOIN TableC ON(TableB.cID= Tablec.cID)
    INNER JOIN TableA ta ON(ta.dID= TableD.dID)
    WHERE (DATE(TableC.date)=date(now()))
```

Answer (score 307, accepted):

You want something more like this:

```
SELECT TableA.*, TableB.*, TableC.*, TableD.*
FROM TableA
    JOIN TableB
        ON TableB.aID = TableA.aID
    JOIN TableC
        ON TableC.cID = TableB.cID
    JOIN TableD
        ON TableD.dID = TableA.dID
WHERE DATE(TableC.date)=date(now())
```

In your example, you are not actually including `TableD`. All you have to do is perform another join just like you have done before.

A note: you will notice that I removed many of your parentheses, as they really are not necessary in most of the cases you had them, and only add confusion when trying to read the code. Proper nesting is the best way to make your code readable and separated out.

Comment: won't select tableN.* duplicate all the matching primary key ID's in the column labels? (question did not specify what output is desired but usually you wouldn't want to do this I think)

Comment: Might I ask why the `JOINTableC` is `ON` `TableC.cID = TableB.cID` and not `TableC.cID = TableA.cID`. I assumed we are joining `TableA` to the other 3 tables.

Answer (score 25):

```
SELECT 
    a.nameA, /* TableA.nameA */
    d.nameD /* TableD.nameD */
FROM TableA a 
    INNER JOIN TableB b on b.aID = a.aID 
    INNER JOIN TableC c on c.cID = b.cID 
    INNER JOIN TableD d on d.dID = a.dID 
WHERE DATE(c.`date`) = CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 4):

You have not joined TableD, merely selected the TableD FIELD (`dID`) from one of the tables.

Answer (score 2):

> **Simple INNER JOIN VIEW code....**

```
CREATE VIEW room_view
AS SELECT a.*,b.*
FROM j4_booking a INNER JOIN j4_scheduling b
on a.room_id = b.room_id;
```

Comment: Not using the OP's table structure ?!