# Join multiple tables on multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I, also, have a question regarding how to join my database tables. My data setup is as follows:

```
MainTable
main_id x y z
1       l m n
2       o p q
SubTableA
main_id extra_id foo bar
1       a        1   4
1       b        2   h
1       c        1   g
2       a        k   er
2       b        k   34
2       c        l   f

SubTableB
main_id extra_id a b c
1       a        v r j
1       c        w r k
2       c        x h l

SubTableC
main_id extra_id mono stereo
2       c        n    null
2       d        z    y
```

I'm trying to achieve the following result:

```
main_id x y z extra_id foo bar a b c mono stereo
1       l m n a        1   4   v r j null null
1       l m n b        2   h         null null
1       l m n c        1   g   w r k null null
2       o p q a        k   er        null null
2       o p q b        k   34        null null
2       o p q c        l   f   x h l n    null
2       o p q d                      z    y
```

To spice things up, sometimes the `extra_id` is null or one of the subtables doesn't contain `main_id` but then I would like the other tables to be joined and null-filled for values that aren't found.
In that case I would like the outcome to be:
`main_id x y z extra_id foo bar a b c null null` for example.

I tried to use [How can I join multiple SQL tables using the IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853586/sql-join-multiple-tables) as template but couldn't get it all the way.

This is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT
  m.*,
  a.*,
  b.*,
  c.*,
FROM
  MainTable m,
  SubTableA a,
  SubTableB b,
  SubTableC c,
WHERE
  m.main_id = a.main_id(+)
  AND a.main_id=b.main_id(+)
  AND a.extra_id=b.extra_id(+)
  AND a.main_id = c.main_id(+)
  AND a.extra_id = c.extra_id(+);
```

Edit:
I want all rows from main table. When they match sub tables on main_id join them for each of the extra_id (which can be more than one for each main_id). And if combination of main_id and extra_id exists in more than one sub table I want them to be joined. Will give more elaborated example when in front of laptop again.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1c9b3/2)

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes you want *left* joins, not right joins - in other words, always show rows from `MainTable` even if there are no related rows in `SubTableA` and the others. This is implied by the sample output with null values for `mono` and `stereo`.

I'd move to the newer join syntax, and when you want a column included you should name it rather than relying on `SELECT *`. `SELECT *` is fine for quick, ad-hoc queries, but for anything more you should name the columns.

I'd also recommend aliasing to cut down on typing. It looks like you were doing that, given the `SC` and `AD` in your example.

```
SELECT
  m.main_id,
  m.x,
  m.y,
  m.z,
  a.extra_id,
  a.foo,
  a.bar,
  b.a,
  b.b,
  b.c,
  c.mono,
  c.stereo
FROM MainTable m
LEFT JOIN SubTableA a
  ON m.main_id = a.main_id
LEFT JOIN SubTableB b
  ON a.main_id = b.main_id AND a.extra_id = b.extra_id
LEFT JOIN SubTableC c
  ON a.main_id = b.main_id AND a.extra_id = c.extra_id
```

Comment: But what if SubTableB contains a main_id that isn't in SubTableA? Would it still work?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your joins.  You want to join Main to A, but keep all the rows that exist in A but don't have a main_id, right?  So you want everything from the RIGHT side of the join.

```
MainTable M RIGHT JOIN SubTableA A ON M.main_id = A.main_id
```

And you want to do this will all tables;

```
SELECT
    A.*
    , B.*
    , C.*
FROM
    MainTable M
     RIGHT JOIN SubTableA A ON M.main_id = A.main_id
     RIGHT JOIN SubTableB B ON M.main_id = B.main_id
     RIGHT JOIN SubTableC C ON M.main_id = C.main_id

WHERE
[some stuff]
```

Note: You may want to try RIGHT OUTER JOINs.
Note2: I was confused by the description. If the row exists in Main but not in a sub-table then you want LEFT - all rows in Main regardless of whether they exist on the other side of the join. If the row exists in a sub-table but not Main then you want a RIGHT OUTER.

P.S. I didn't realize this was for Oracle, so I hope it's not too different.