# How to get all data from 2 tables using foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the result of separating a single table in two:

```
Table users:
    user_id (pk, ai)
    email
    password
    last_login

Table data:
    user_id (fk to users.user_id)
    data_1
    data_2
```

To select a single record when there was only one table:

```
SELECT users.email, users.password, data.data_1, data.data_2
FROM users,data 
WHERE users.email='$user_email' AND users.user_id=data.user_id";
```

How do I get all records from both tables having the rows connected by users.user_id=data.user_id?

```
Row1: email, password, data_1, data2
Row2: email, password, data_1, data2
Row3: email, password, data_1, data2
Row4: email, password, data_1, data2
...
```

Comment: `SELECT users.email, users.password, data.data_1, data.data_2
FROM users JOIN data ON  users.user_id=data.user_id`

Comment: This question has been asked a lot before. heres 1 example just from a quick google search. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853586/sql-join-multiple-tables

Comment: This only grabs a single record based on an given email. I am looking for way to join the 2 tables and get all rows (but only the email, password, data_1, and data_2 columns).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using explicit `join` syntax could help you. Rewrite your query to:

```
SELECT 
    users.email, users.password, data.data_1, data.data_2
FROM 
    users
INNER JOIN 
    data 
ON
    users.user_id=data.user_id
WHERE 
    users.email='$user_email'
```

and get all rows without a WHERE condition:

```
SELECT 
    users.email, users.password, data.data_1, data.data_2
FROM 
    users
INNER JOIN 
    data 
ON
    users.user_id=data.user_id
```

It separates the concerns: conditions that join tables from conditions that restricts the result set.

Answer (score 5):

have you tried this?

```
SELECT users.email, users.password, data.data1, data.data2
FROM users,data 
WHERE users.user_id=data.user_id
```

or this?

```
SELECT users.email, users.password, data.data1, data.data2
FROM users inner join data on users.user_id=data.user_id
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do it
as follow...

```
SELECT users.email, users.password, data.data_1, data.data_2
FROM users,data 
WHERE users.user_id=data.user_id AND users.email='$user_email'
```

just copy and past above query you may get expected result..

Comment: Its also a join query. Its called an implicit join where JOIN keyword is not used.

Answer (score 2):

To join the userData table to Users try this:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.email, u.password, u.last_login
FROM users u
JOIN userData ud ON (u.userID = ud.userID)
```

This will return all data where the User ID in the Users table matches the User ID in the userData table.

**Edit**
In addition, there are different kinds of joins:

- INNER
- OUTER
- LEFT
- RIGHT

For more information on this and their differences check out this handy reference:
http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.email, users.password, data.data_1, data.data_2 FROM 
users JOIN data ON  users.user_id=data.user_id
WHERE users.email='$user_email';
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use inner join which returns records when there is a common field matches in both tables.. 
for ex in your case

```
select * from table1 
  inner join table2 on table1.user_id=table2.user_id
```

will return all the records in both the table by matching the common fields