# How to get all data from 3 tables using a relationship/mapping table with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

I have 2 tables with a 3rd mapping table that only have ids(foreign key) of the two tables.
is it possible to get a result like this with just one query

```
╔═══════╦═══════╗
║user_id║ data  ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║   1   ║ {a, c}║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║   2   ║   b   ║
╚═══════╩═══════╝

Table users:
    user_id (pk, fk to relationship.userid)

Table data:
    data_id (fk to data.data_id)
    data

Table relationship:
    user_id (fk of user.user_id)
    data_id (fk of data.data_id)
```

this is a sample data

```
USER
+-------+
|user_id|
|-------|
|   1   |
+-------+
|   2   |
+-------+

RELATIONSHIP
+-------+-------+
|user_id|data_id|
+-------+-------+
|   1   |   1   |
+-------+-------+
|   1   |   3   |
+-------+-------+
|   2   |   2   |
+-------+-------+

DATA
+-------+----+
|data_id|data|
+-------+----+
|   1   | a  |
+-------+----+
|   2   | b  |
+-------+----+
|   3   | c  |
+-------+----+
```

with the join query the result repeats user_id for each data it have
similar to this [How to get all data from 2 tables using foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24332294/how-to-get-all-data-from-2-tables-using-foreign-key)

the problem with that is i am looping through the result in my php code to list users with all their datas once not multiple times for ever data the user have.

Comment: Read on MySQL [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and see if it works for you.

Comment: What have you tried so far????  SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade I typed them manually. the first one i copied it from another page.
@Eric i have tried many, i posted this to know if it is even possible what i was trying to do. what im working on have more tables and relation.
i am already getting kind of what i want its just that it is not returning them in one row for each user.
SELECT `user`.`user_id`, `data`.`data` FROM `user` JOIN `relation` ON `user`.`user_id` = `relation`.`user_id` JOIN `data` ON `relation`.`data_id` = `data`.`data_id`.
if you know, answer it. you could have said it possible or not.

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `group_concat()` :

```
SELECT r.user_id, group_concat(d.data)
FROM relationship r
JOIN data d ON r.data_id = d.data_id
GROUP BY r.user_id;
```

Comment: Thank you that actually worked!

for anyone who is interested.
SELECT user.user_id, group_concat(data.data) FROM user JOIN relation ON user.user_id = relation.user_id JOIN data ON relation.data_id = data.data_id group by user.user_id.