# Joining 3 tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, join

I need to join three tables in Oracle; I have code but I am not sure if it is totally right.

```
FROM DISTRICT D1 
JOIN EMPLOYEE E1 ON D1.DISTRICT_ID = E1.DISTRICT_ID
JOIN TOTAL_PAB T1 ON E1.EMP_ID = T1.EMP_ID
```

I need to join the table DISTRICT, EMPLOYEE, AND TOTAL_PAB.
Where do the primary and foreign keys go in this join table statement?

- Primary key for EMPLOYEE is EMP_ID and FK is DISTRICT_ID.
- Primary key for DISTRICT is DISTRICT_ID and FK is SUPERINTENDENT_ID.
- Primary key for TOTAL_PAB is PAB_ID and FK is EMP_ID.

Comment: I suggest checking out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853586/sql-join-multiple-tables

Comment: That looks okay.  Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0):

The query seems legit, but you should give us some more informations for a better answer.

Generally, it's not important if a field is key or not: the important thing is that ONLY fields in "ON" part of the join statement will be used for matching rows.