# JOINT TABLE MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have table:

**tb_keterangan**

```
colDate    | colKeteranganID | colUser ID
2012-08-01 |               1 |          1
2012-08-03 |               2 |          1
```

I have query like this:

```
SELECT cal.myDate as colDate,
       t.colJamMasuk,
       t.colJamKeluar,
       t.colTerlambat,
       t.colLemburPagi,
       t.colLemburSore,
       b.colKeterangan,
       c.colKeteranganID
  FROM (SELECT s.start_date + INTERVAL (tb_days.day) DAY as myDate
          FROM (SELECT DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(2015, 31), INTERVAL (07-2) MONTH) AS start_date,
                       DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(2015, 1), INTERVAL (07) MONTH) AS end_date) AS s
          JOIN tb_days
            ON tb_days.day < DATEDIFF(s.end_date, s.start_date)) AS cal
  LEFT JOIN tb_libur AS b
    ON b.colTanggal = cal.myDate
  LEFT JOIN tb_kehadiran AS t
    ON t.colDate >= cal.myDate AND
       t.colDate < cal.myDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND
       t.colUserID = 1
  ORDER BY colDate
```

I want to  join tb_keterangan table to my query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL join multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853586/sql-join-multiple-tables)

Comment: That query can't possibly execute. You have a reference to a table alias `c` (as `c.colKeteranganID`), but there is no table in the query which has `c` as an alias. In addition, you'll have to explain what the join criteria should be. Thanks.