# Nested select on sql

Tags: sql

I have this structure on database (bad structure indeed)

Country

> id_country | desc_country

Region

> id_region  | id_country | desc_region

City

> id_city    | id_region  | desc_city

Employee

> id_city | nom | ape

How I can if is possible recover all employees with their respective descriptions (desc_country, desc_region, desc_city) from id_city of Employee on one sql select.

Comment: Looks like a fairly standard normalised structure and you just need to inner join all tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I join multiple SQL tables using the IDs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853586/how-can-i-join-multiple-sql-tables-using-the-ids)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will just need to do a join on each one:

```
SELECT e.nom, ct.desc_country, r.desc_region, c.desc_city 
FROM Employee AS e
INNER JOIN City as c
  ON e.id_city = c.id_city
INNER JOIN Region as r
  ON c.id_region = r.id_region
INNER JOIN Country as ct
  ON ct.id_country = r.id_country
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT cy.id_country, cy.desc_country, r.id_region, r.id_country, r.desc_region, ct.id_city, ct.id_region, ct. desc_city, e.id_city, e.nom, e.ape

FROM Employee AS e
JOIN City AS ct 
ON e.id_city=ct.id_city
JOIN Region AS r
ON ct.id_region=r.id_region
JOIN Country AS cy
ON r.id_country=cy.id_country
```