# Select from a select query

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this query for a page similar to "instagram" (no I am not trying to make an instagram)

I am using this code for it

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM camera_web ORDER BY url ASC LIMIT 50');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo '<img src="'.$row['url'].'" valign="middle" />'.$row['username'].' <br><hr>  <b>'.$row['user_id'].'</b>  <i>'.$row['description'].'</i><br />';
    }
?>
```

It shows pictures from the table "camera_web" but also the user_id from the table.

When someone publishes a photo I see the photo but not the username, instead it is the user_id, how can I do to make the query select the select "username" from my "users" table where ID = (user_id).

I can't explain any better, if you do not quite understand I'll advance.

Comment: use join @Omega Cebbo

Comment: You need to JOIN your users table to the query. Example (`SELECT camera_web.url, camera_web.description, users.username FROM camera_web LEFT JOIN users ON camera_web.user_id = users.user_id ORDER BY camera_web.url ASC LIMIT 50`

Comment: However, you need to stop using `mysql_` methods - they were deprecated in later versions of PHP5 and removed in PHP7 - look into `mysqli_` or `pdo` (which you can also use with MySQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I join multiple SQL tables using the IDs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853586/how-can-i-join-multiple-sql-tables-using-the-ids)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you join both table using foreign key

```
select `user_table_name`.`user`, `camera_web`.`url` 
from `camera_web` 
left join `user_table_name` 
on `user_table_name`.`id` = `camera_web`.`user_id` 
order by `camera_web`.`url` asc limit 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `LEFT JOIN users` table by `user_id`:

```
SELECT cw.* , u.username
FROM camera_web cw
LEFT JOIN users u
ON u.id = cw.user_id
ORDER BY cw.url ASC LIMIT 50
```

Comment: cw stands for camera_web I guess?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JOIN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT c.*, u.username
FROM camera_web c JOIN users u ON c.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY c.url LIMIT 50;
```

This would still select both `user_id` and `username`, if you don't want `user_id`, you can replace `c.*` with comma separated list of fields (e.g. c.id, c.picture etc).