# SQL RIGHT OUTER JOIN statement

Tags: mysql

I have an entry level SQL problem I'm working on but the question is confusing.. and I'm not sure I have all of the code correct.

The directions are:

> Use the blog database Write a SQL RIGHT OUTER JOIN statement that
>   joins the user_id column from the blog.posts table, the name column of
>   the blog.users table and the body column of the blog.posts table
>   together.

The code I have so far is:

```
USE blog;
SELECT posts.user_id, users.name, posts.body
FROM blog
RIGHT OUTER JOIN user_id ON
blog.name = posts.id;
```

I feel like I'm missing something in the last part of the code or in the join portion of the code.. Any tips or direction on this question would be amazing. Thank you.

Comment: It should be RIGHT OUTER JOIN posts ON....

Comment: yo man when you're joining 3 tables aren't you supposed to choose three `ON` fields, not two? Like, you gotta be using user_id iI think. Three times.

Comment: "RIGHT OUTER JOIN posts ON" didn't work.

Comment: @mekkanizer what do you mean by using it 3 times?

Comment: @KristenR nah I mistook SQL syntax in previous comment. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9853636/3296093