# How can I do a select inside this select? MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is my Select

```
SELECT id, name, price, category, url, image1 FROM `Products_items` WHERE active='y' and stockCount >= 1 ORDER BY views DESC
```

But I need to know **column category_url** from **table Product_categories**.

I tried this one but doesnt work

```
SELECT id, name, price, category, url, image1 FROM `Products_items` WHERE active='y' and stockCount >= 1 ORDER BY views DESC
SELECT url FROM Product_categories WHERE id=Products_items.category
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` connects two tables.

Comment: How do you relation products and product categories?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I join multiple SQL tables using the IDs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853586/how-can-i-join-multiple-sql-tables-using-the-ids)

Comment: @Troyer product_items.category is Product_categories.id

Comment: It is absolutely unfair to edit your question and add some follow-up questions that were not in scope of the original one. If you have any follow-up questions, then ask them separately. Although, there are dozens of questions here on SO alone that deal with how to print out results of a query from php...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JOIN to join two tables, you have more information [there](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). In case you have a foreign key on the products_items table related to the category you can do this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.price, a.category, b.url, a.image1 
FROM `Products_items` a 
LEFT JOIN Product b ON a.category_id = b.id 
WHERE a.active='y' and a.stockCount >= 1 ORDER BY a.views DESC
```

Comment: @LucasFerraz Check it now.

Comment: You ROCK! Thank you so much!

Comment: Pls do not encourage incorrect behaviour by answering duplicate questions and then follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0):

A `JOIN` clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a related column between them.

```
SELECT * FROM Products_items as items JOIN Product_categories as categories ON items.category = categories.id;
```