# Get all countries states and cities in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have three tables with the following data:

```
countries
+-----+----------+
| id  |   name   |
+-----+----------+
| 1   | country1 |
| 7   | country2 |
+-----+----------+

states
+-----+----------+------------+
| id  |   name   | country_id |
+-----+----------+------------+
| 3   | state1   |     1      |
| 9   | state2   |     7      |
| 11  | state3   |     1      |
| 17  | state4   |     1      |
+-----+----------+------------+

cities
+-----+----------+------------+
| id  |   name   |  state_id  |
+-----+----------+------------+
| 5   | city1    |     3      |
| 6   | city2    |     9      |
| 22  | city3    |     9      |
| 24  | city4    |     17     |
| 25  | city5    |     11     |
| 26  | city6    |     11     |
+-----+----------+------------+
```

I’m trying to select all data so that I can generate the following output:

```
+-----+---------------------------+--------+-------+
| id  |   table_name   | country  | state  |  city |
+-----+---------------------------+--------+-------+
| 1   |    countries   | country1 |        |       |
| 3   |      states    | country1 | state1 |       |
| 5   |      cities    | country1 | state1 | city1 |
| 11  |      states    | country1 | state3 |       |
| 25  |      cities    | country1 | state3 | city5 |
| 26  |      cities    | country1 | state3 | city6 |
| 17  |      states    | country1 | state4 |       |
| 24  |      cities    | country1 | state4 | city4 |
| 7   |    countries   | country2 |        |       |
| 9   |      states    | country2 | state2 |       |
| 5   |      cities    | country2 | state2 | city2 |
| 5   |      cities    | country2 | state2 | city3 |
+-----+---------------------------+--------+-------+
```

I know it’s challenging, but I was wondering if that is possible to generate such a result with a SELECT or can it only be done programmatically? Thanks!

Comment: what has this got to do with js?

Comment: go have a look at joins

Comment: No you can't use union, union requires common number of columns in all the tables

Comment: @Jim Macaulay you can if you provide dummy values..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I join multiple SQL tables using the IDs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853586/how-can-i-join-multiple-sql-tables-using-the-ids)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need these 3 SQL statements:

All Cities:

```
SELECT cit.id, 'cities', cont.name, st.name, cit.name 
FROM countries cont 
INNER JOIN states st ON  cont.id = st.country_id 
INNER JOIN  join cities cit ON st.id = cit.state_id
```

All states:

```
SELECT stat.id, 'states', cont.name, st.name, '' 
FROM  countries cont 
INNER JOIN states st ON cont.id = st.country_id
```

All countries;

```
SELECT cont.id, 'countries', cont.name, '', '' FROM countries cont
```

Then you can combine them all  like

```
SELECT cit.id, 'cities', cont.name, st.name, cit.name 
FROM countries cont 
INNER JOIN states st ON  cont.id = st.country_id 
INNER JOIN  join cities cit ON st.id = cit.state_id

  UNION ALL

SELECT stat.id, 'states', cont.name, st.name, '' 
FROM  countries cont 
INNER JOIN states st ON cont.id = st.country_id

  UNION ALL

SELECT cont.id, 'countries', cont.name, '', '' FROM countries cont
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
SELECT  C.id,  C.name AS table_name, 'country1' AS country, S.name AS state, CI.city 
FROM COUNTRIES C
FULL OUTER JOIN STATES S
ON (C.ID = S.ID)
FULL OUTER JOIN CITIES CI
ON (C.ID=CI.ID);

Or you can use

SELECT  C.id,  C.name AS table_name, 'country1' AS country, S.name AS state, CI.city 
FROM COUNTRIES C, STATES S, CITIES CI
WHERE C.ID = (+)S.ID AND
C.ID=(+)CI.ID;
```

Comment: I don't think MySQL supports full outer join.

Comment: (+)S.ID is an invalid construct. As a matter of interest which flavour of sql supports this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd written this before I saw @nos had already supplied a virtually identical answer. This version adds field aliases, sorts the data as per the OP's sample output and avoids a typo.

```
select
    c.id,
    'countries' as table_name,
    c.name as country,
    '' as state,
    '' as city
from countries c
union
select
    s.id,
    'states' as table_name,
    c.name as country,
    s.name as state,
    '' as city
from countries c
JOIN states s ON c.id = s.country_id
union
select
    ci.id,
    'cities' as table_name,
    c.name as country,
    s.name as state,
    ci.name as city
from countries c
JOIN states s ON c.id = s.country_id
JOIN cities ci ON s.id = ci.state_id
order by country, state, city
```