# How to make multiple table join?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to extract some data from my shop's database. The data I want is in four tables: `ps_order_detail`, `ps_orders`, `ps_carrier` and `ps_customer`. The main table is `ps_order_detail`. For each record of `ps_order_detail` I want to attach corresponding values from other tables based on id's: `id_order`, `id_customer` and `id_carrier`. The problem is that the base table (`ps_order_detail`) contains only `id_order` and the other id's are in `ps_orders` table. Do you know how can I solve this?

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a pretty basic `JOIN` query.

Comment: You can `JOIN` table A to B, then B to C, then B to D, etc.. They don't all have to go directly to A.

Comment: I'd assume, select from `ps_order_detail` join to `ps_orders`  and then join the others from there using `ps_orders`

Comment: Oh okay. would it be something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853586/how-can-i-join-multiple-sql-tables-using-the-ids?

Comment: just join all 4 tables like @AaronDietz said

Comment: Google: `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear on the data layouts of the tables, but the query would look something like this:

```
select . . . 
from ps_order_detail od join
     ps_orders o
     using (id_order) join
     ps_customer c
     using (id_customer) join
     ps_carrier ca
     using (id_carrier)
```